# Any GOOD tutorials?

Tags: texturing, scene

I'm new to blender 2.8. I have used Blender 2.78 in the past and had some good tutorials bookmarked but I'm having no luck finding good tutorials for 2.8. Danged near ever tutorial I find is made by someone who rattles on too fast, uses too many key board short cuts and fails to cover key steps. I've made some objects, I need to UV unwrap them, texture them (like glass), then set up a light scene and view them. I am making items for Skyrim SSE. I remember a tutorial series by a woman for 2.78, and she was very thorough, and actually showed HOW to do these things. Does anyone know of a good channel?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for tutorials. (See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic)

Comment: I'm not asking somebody to make me a tutorial, I'm asking if anybody can provide a link to better tutorials than the ones on the Blender page. Why don't you read the page you referred me to. Because there is no answer to my question there.

Comment: *"I'm asking if anybody can provide a link to better tutorials than the ones on the Blender page"* you were not asking for that. Read your question, there's no mention you already saw that page. *"tutorial ... actually showed HOW to do these things"* if you followed it in 2.78 you would know how to do that in 2.8. Versions don't differ that much